# Symfony increments choice index

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In a show template that displays the text of a choice field, I find that for some reason I must subtract 1 from the index of the choice in order to properly display the chosen value.  Why is this?

An example:
Choice field is based on the following table:

```
vid description
1   Critical
2   Emergency
3   FACE
4   General Dist.
5   Let's Talk Turkey
6   TEFAP
7   Emergency plus General
8   TEFAP plus General
```

Controller gets this with:

```
$type = $em->getRepository('ManaClientBundle:Contactdesc')->findAll();
```

Template snippet:

```
Attribute(type, vid) [vid={{ vid }}]:{{ dump(attribute(type, vid)) }}
```

Yields, for example, this:

```
Attribute(type, vid) [vid=4]:class Mana\ClientBundle\Entity\Contactdesc#834 (2) { private $vid => int(5) private $description => string(17) "Let's Talk Turkey" }
```

Notice that the vid for the client is 4, yet the dump shows it as 5.  HUH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays are 0-indexed, so the index 4 of an array is the fifth element. Your snippet doesn't show the item for a vid=4 but for the index 4 of the array...

Comment: Where is the array here?  Type is an object, and my assumption has been that using the client's vid would return the description.  If I subtract 1 from the vid, when the form on which this data appears is submitted I get an error related to not finding vid = -1!  If the above is the incorrect method for displaying the intended result, what is the correct method?

Comment: It is, of course, possible to turn the entity into an array in the controller and have it behave as desired.  Does this mean there's no object-oriented means to getting the correct choice description without churning out an array?